# How can i make inner joins with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can i implement the following query using laravel Eloquent data object model ?

```
select links.title, school_status.school_code 
     from links inner join school_status
     on links.id=school_status.link_id 
where 
    links.id!=35 and school_status.academic_year = '2014-15'
```

in this query, year is a variable i could change within the controller. How to implement this ?

Comment: Read the docs http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: its weired. difficult to understand..

Comment: `DB::table(..)->join(..)->select(..)->where(..)->where(..)->get()` - it's not, really.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not hard to convert RAW SQL queries, but you can try this:

```
DB::table('links')
          ->select('links.title', 'school_status.school_code')
          ->join('school_status','links.id','=','school_status.link_id')
          ->where('links.id','!=',35)
          ->where('school_status.academic_year','=','2014-15')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on laravel belongsTo,hasMany for Eloquent object model .

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do it with query builder then the below code work for you

```
DB::table('links')->join('school_status','links.id','=','school_status.link_id')->select('links.title', 'school_status.school_code')->where('links.id','!=',35)->where('school_status.academic_year','=','2014-15')->get();
```

But if you want to do it with eloquent for this first you have to specify the relationship b.w table

For that Read Laravel 4.1 doc